# Composite C1 - 'URL Aliases' bug - 301 always goes back to 302

Tags: c1-cms

I have downloaded the new version of 'Url Aliases' 1.0.3.

Whenever I set a 301 redirect - it goes back to 302 if I go back and look at it. I think this is a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Url Aliases v. 1.0.4 is online. It fixes the issue.